# The `npm ci` command can only install with an existing package-lock.json or remote npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1

Tags: node.js, heroku

I made one tiny text change to an old(er) Node application which works as intended in my local development system, including the `npm ci` command, but it fails to deploy to Heroku with this error:

```
npm ERR! The `npm ci` command can only install with an existing package-lock.json or
remote npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1
```

but I have a `package-lock.json` with:

```
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
```

This application used to deploy just fine but it's been a year of two since the last deploy so I'm guessing this is some underlying issue with the Heroku deployment, perhaps with the updated build-packs. The application is currently using `heroku-18` but it's trying to upgrade to `heroku-22` in the same deploy.

I've tried different versions of Node and NPM though I can't go above Node 12 without making significant updates to this legacy application...which I'd   r e a a a l l y   like to avoid.

Any ideas on how to tickle this away?

**Full Error**

```
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  15.3.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   7.0.14
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 15.3.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 15.3.0...
remote:        npm 7.0.14 already installed with node
remote:        
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
remote:        Module installation may take longer for this build
remote:        
remote: -----> Prebuild
remote:        Running heroku-prebuild
remote:        
remote:        > snazzywiz@2.1.1 heroku-prebuild
remote:        > npm --global install pushstate-server@3.0.1; npm --global install @angular/cli
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        added 44 packages, and audited 44 packages in 3s
remote:        
remote:        10 vulnerabilities (5 low, 3 moderate, 2 high)
remote:        
remote:        To address issues that do not require attention, run:
remote:          npm audit fix
remote:        
remote:        To address all issues, run:
remote:          npm audit fix --force
remote:        
remote:        Run `npm audit` for details.
remote:        
remote:        added 209 packages, and audited 209 packages in 8s
remote:        
remote:        25 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote: npm notice 
remote: npm notice New major version of npm available! 7.0.14 -> 8.19.2
remote: npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.19.2>
remote: npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.19.2` to update!
remote: npm notice 
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! The `npm ci` command can only install with an existing package-lock.json or
remote:        npm ERR! npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or
remote:        npm ERR! later to generate a package-lock.json file, then try again.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.ULXke/_logs/2022-09-17T19_15_54_600Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

**Note:** There are several SO questions with the same "The `npm ci` command can only..." error message but triggered from different scenarios but none from just a deploy to Heroku.

Comment: This is a curious buildpack. Node LTS versions are 14, 16, and 18, installing 15 (which is essentially a dev-only version) would take some doing O_o Having said that: try to get a hold of that `/tmp/npmcache.ULXke/_logs/2022-09-17T19_15_54_600Z-debug.log` file, because it's possible it's not talking about _your_ package-lock

Comment: Yeah -- not sure why it's doing that. The `engines` is specifying 12. The build-pack is Heroku's 18 build-pack: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-18-stack

Comment: 12 is... quite dead by now. So I'm not surprised heroku's flat out refusing to use that. However, even if you say you're using the node 18 build pack, that log says you're not, it's using "the heroku-22 stack" (third line of the log you're showing), and taps into Node 15. Time to go through your files and see if any of them are considered "active files" as far as Heroku is concerned?

Comment: The configured build-pack is 18 but it's trying to upgrade to 22 on this same deploy...which may be part of the problem. Unfortunately, I just tried upgrading to Node 16 but sadly I'm getting lots of run problems (with sass ATM).

Comment: if you're still on 12, you are probably still using the ancient and now dead node-sass: remember to change that dependency from `node-sass` to just `sass`.